# Get custom guard logged name in blade

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i'm using `custom guard`

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

i want to get admin name on blade
so i call it using

`{{ Auth::guard('admin')->name }}`

but i got error

> Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::$name

how can i achieve this on **laravel 5.3**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you trying to get the name of the SessionGuard object or the name of the user that is signed in using the `admin` guard?

This might be what you are looking for:

```
Auth::guard('admin')->user()->name;
```

Just note that the above will only work if the user is logged in, as the `user` method will return `null` when they're not logged in. Here's how you'd check if they are logged in:

```
Auth::guard('admin')->check();
```